# Correct way to copy column value from primary table to another second and third model in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I want to copy `username` of the Django auth model to each level of the tables below.
I tried `ForeignKey`, but what is the correct way to just copy a username to second or third level table below?
Is it safe to have such two foreign keys in this case?

I want to avoid joins. I want value to be copied so I can run simple select query without join because I have to run complex data visualization and analysis on `Tracking`; doing joins for that will be very complicated

```
Django User: `username`
 |
 |-> Order #copy username here
       |
       |-> Tracking #copy username here


from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Order(models.Model):
    primary_user = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field='username', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Order_number = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    objects = models.Manager()


class Tracking(models.Model):
    primary_user = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field='username', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Order_number_copied = models.ForeignKey(Order, to_field='Order_number', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    objects = models.Manager()
```

Comment: Why even have a foreign key from `Tracking` to `User`? that relationship is already made by the foreign key to `Order` (`Order_number_copied`). Doing so is only increasing your own work and difficulties.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Though relationship is built I want the value of `username` copied in all tables below which is separate from the foreign key.

Comment: What is the benefit of doing that? You already have the relationship built with the foreign key to `Order` which has the foreign key to `User`. Simply having an extra field in the table for that is redundant. If it is for display purposes, your user likely won't directly interact with the database right? You can join the tables, etc. before displaying anything.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I want to avoid joins. I want value to be copied so I can run simple select query without join because I have to run complex data visualization and analysis on `Tracking`; doing joins for that will be very complicated.

Comment: Analysis and reporting often requires a different data structure to the standard transactional one. However, in this case it is better to have a completely separate reporting database with its custom data model optimised for this purpose, rather than trying to mix the two data models together.